# How to show that : If $\int x^n f(x) dx = 0$ for all $n$ then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to show that :

> If $\int x^n f(x) dx = 0$ for all $n$ then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$

My attempts:
We can deduce that :

$$\int \sum_i a_i x^i f(x) dx = 0 $$ for all $a_i$'s

To the contrary if $f$ has a support $D$, then we can take $a_i$'s so that $\sum_i a_i x^i$ has the same sign of $f$ and $$\int \sum_i a_i x^i f(x) dx > 0 $$ which is a contrary.

I think this is not correct, since `we can take $a_i$'s so that $\sum_i a_i x^i$ has the same sign of $f$` might not be correct.

Also, using [Stone–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) might be helpful.

Comment: Any chance you want to work with a *definite* integral, rather than an indefinite integral?

Comment: Is $f$, say, continuous? Smooth?

Comment: @MarkMcClure Unfortunately no!

Comment: @anomaly Not necessarily.

Comment: Is there any condition on $n$ (say, $n\geq 0$)? Also if $f$ is not continuous, then take $f(x)=1$ if $x=1$, $f(x)=0$ if $x\neq 1$...

Comment: This question is very strange. For an indefinite integral, it doesn't even make sense to require that it's zero, since it is only determined up to an additive constant anyway.

Comment: In response to another comment, you might also want to add that $f = 0$ a.e., otherwise this would certainly not be true